# How to fix 'do not commit' error in Sympy repository tests after cloning for contribution?

Tags: automated-tests, sympy, open-source

Sympy repository fails some tests right after clone.

I want to contribute to sympy by fixing a bug, but when I cloned and set up the environment and run ./bin/test as advised I get an error saying do not commit. Why I'm getting this failed tests on a fresh clone? Did I do something wrong?

[image: Error message from running bin/test]

Following is the summary of the test output.

> ============ 5 failed, 10480 passed, 461 skipped, 193 deselected, 317 xfailed, 5 xpassed, 3 warnings in 1548.08s (0:25:48) =============

Should I ignore the errors and proceed? What should I do? I run the tests in a conda environment as advised in sympy/docs/contribution.